# Mnemonic for which of $\vee$ and $\wedge$ means OR and which means AND

Tags: soft-question, notation, propositional-calculus

I can never remember which is which. What's a good mnemonic?

(In the 15 minutes so far this question has existed, I've seen one answer be edited and one comment be deleted for mixing them up, which I guess comes to show how easy it is to do that.)

Comment: Well $\wedge$ already looks like the beginning of a letter A for And

Comment: If you already know $\cup$ is union and $\cap$ is intersection, then $\vee$ is in the same direction as $\cup$ since $x \in A \cup B$ is equivalent to $x \in A \vee x \in B$, and $\wedge$ is in the same direction as $\cap$ since $x \in A \cap B$ is equivalent to $x \in A \wedge x \in B$.

Comment: Same question for $\Delta$ and $\nabla$.

Comment: $\lor$ resembles $\cup,$ the first letter of $\cup$nion.... $(x\in A \lor x\in B)\iff (x\in A\cup B)$

Comment: It goes to show you that sometimes English, for all its shortcomings, is often the clearest way to express something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just remember that $\wedge$ looks like an A for And.

Comment: good one..............

Answer (score 3):

$\vee$ and $\wedge$ correspond to $\cup$ and $\cap$, respectively, so if you can remember which is union and which is intersection, it may help you remember which is OR and which is AND, because they look similar.  The union symbol looks like a U so that may help, too.

Comment: You could also take the $\lor$ to be like a bucket, which fills itself up with everything on its left side and its right side, similar to a union operation you're talking about..

Answer (score 3):

the 'or' is smiling cause it's easier to satisfy.

Comment: Briliant..............

Comment: I can only accept one answer, but I think this one is the best suggestion for $\vee$. A nice thing about it is that it suggests a corresponding mnemonic for $\wedge$: it's a frown because it's picky.

Comment: I like how this one and Bram28's don't depend on the language used.

Answer (score 1):

$\vee$ resembles the letter v, which is the first letter of "vel", the Latin word for "or".

Comment: Has "vee", the latex symbol for it, to do with "vel"?

Comment: Or with velcro, which sticks together?

Answer (score 1):

I see the $\lor$ as a physical structure that precariously balances on a point, but will easily tip to one side or the other.

Comment: Also, $\wedge$ is a structure standing firm on its left leg **and** it's right leg.  This is an amusing answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

$\wedge$ looks like A for and, and $\vee$ looks like r for or. Totally subjective.

Comment: You must write your r's pretty weird. ;P

Comment: @Bye_World I mean, if you decrease the first derivative of the left part, and decrease the second derivative of the right part, $\vee$ starts to look like an r. :)

Comment: Fair enough. +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the latex-commands for these symbols are a good mnemonic. 
Pronouncing $\vee$ sounds like "wedge", so you type it in, and it gives $\wedge$, the other one. You only need to remember that the wrong one was AND.

Comment: How does pronouncing $\vee$ sound like "wedge"?

Comment: @JonasMeyer The letter $V$ (for $\vee$) is pronounced as "w" in the beginning of the word wedge.

Comment: In what language/dialect?  I'm confused.

Comment: @JonasMeyer In English. How do you pronounce the letter $V$ with the first sound? How do you pronounce $w$ in the beginning of "wedge"? For me this is the same, but you are right, I am not native English, so I could be wrong (also with "w").

Comment: IPA for the English pronunciation of "V" is [vi:]. IPA for the English pronunciation of "wedge" is [wɛdʒ],  I copied these from Wiktionary but these agree with my experience as native English speaker (US).  Typically in English "v" and "w" match with IPA. (Further confusion can arise because although I know little German or Latin, I think "w" in German is pronounced as "v" in English, and "v" in Latin is pronounced as "w" in English.)